# FQL not returning all items in stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am building a web app that allows users to post to Facebook as well as view their news feed (among a bunch of other things).

This: https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts returns way to many records. It returns EVERYTHING.

To limit the results to Link, Photo, Status Message, Post, and Video, I opted to use FQL. I using the following in my call:

```
SELECT post_id, source_id, actor_id, target_id, message, attachment, permalink, type FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND type IN (80,247,46,128,56) AND is_hidden = 0
```

The problem is that I am getting back only records created by my app.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, all that is required is a LIMIT statement. It works fine now that I have added a LIMIT.